# How to find hidden characters in excel

Tags: excel, vba, character

Today I have an odd issue. The text seen in excel is not the same as what the program sees.

In my cell I see.

> [NOM DU GARANT], une société en commandite constituée et enregistrée en vertu de la loi Canadain (‍‍‍ci‍-après le « garant »)

but when I load this into a variable in VBA and print it out in my immediate window I get the following.

> ?sText
>
> [NOM DU GARANT], une société en commandite constituée et enregistrée en vertu de la loi Canadain (???ci?­????après le « garant »)

When I pasted the cell here this is what I get.

> [NOM DU GARANT], une société en commandite constituée et enregistrée en vertu de la loi Canadain (‍‍‍ci‍­‍‍‍‍après le « garant »)

When I go into the cell to I could delete the "hidden" characters.

My question is how can I find / remove / see these hidden characters?

Also is there a way to mitigate this issue. I assume these issues come from people copying from a French MS Word application and pasting into this Excel cell (I have no concrete evidence to support this).

Comment: I think the problem is linked to character encoding and not hidden characters. What language is your system in? what about Word and Excel? What language settings do you have for your keyboard? These *could* all affect the text. (and I have to say: "...la loi Canad**ienne**", please)

Comment: "... la loi Canadienne" is just junk data I threw in there. Considering that this workbook is used by multiple people on various machines I have to say that the language of the system could be English or French same with the applications. The only thing I can say is that eventually everyone will be using MS-*-2016 but not everyone has migrated yet. To answer to comment specifically my system is in English but bing for some reason thinks the system is French. The language of the keyboard is US English but I do change it to French to use accents. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the VBA Editor does not display most UNICODE characters.  Specifically, it's ability to display characters is limited to those on the Windows Code Page 1252 (the 8-byte characters).

It can manipulate higher characters, but they won't be displayed in the immediate window (or message boxes, for that matter).

I'm not sure why you feel you need to remove these characters, but:

You can determine the errant characters by displaying each character one at a time, and converting to both standard character code, and Unicode character codes.

In Excel, you might do:

```
A1:  your_text_string
B2:  =MID($A$1,ROWS($1:1),1)
C2:  =CODE(B2)
D2:  =UNICODE(B2)
```

Select B2:D2 and fill down as far as needed.

You can do something similar in VBA.

Your text string includes the Unicode ZWJ (zero-width-joiner) character for which the decimal code is 8205.  So, although this works perfectly OK on your worksheet, it converts to `?`'s in the VBA editor.

If you need to remove them, you can do it on the worksheet with

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,UNICHAR(8205),"")
```

or, the equivalent VBA code:

```
replace([a1],chrw(8205),"")
```

If you are not familiar, suggest internet search for ZWJ, the VBA `ChrW` function, and the Excel `UNICHAR` function.

If this is not an isolated instance, but you need to have a routine to remove any characters which cannot be displayed by the VBA editor, you can try this:

```
Option Explicit
Function removeChars(s As String)
    Dim i As Long, l As Long, sTemp As String
    Dim ch As String

For i = 1 To Len(s)
    ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
    If AscW(ch) <= 255 Then
        sTemp = sTemp & ch
    End If
Next i    

removeChars = sTemp

End Function
```

And, to show it works, here are screenshots of a `MsgBox` generated from the raw text, and the text produced by the `removeChars` UDF above:

[image]

[image]

I don't know if it would be any faster, but here is another UDF using Regular Expressions which can also do the same thing:

```
Option Explicit
Function removeChars(s As String)
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "[^\x00-\xFF]+"
    .Global = True
    removeChars = .Replace(s, "")
End With

End Function
```

This last UDF can be sped up a bit by using early-binding, and, if you have many strings to process, by doing it within VBA arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You may recognize cells with such text by comparing `Len(Range.Text)` and `Len(Range.Value2)`.

You may experiment with `StrConv(string, vbFromUnicode)` and `StrConv(string, vbUnicode)`.

You may clean it with `WorksheetFunction.Clean()` (works only on lower ASCII codes).
If clean is not effective, I would try to find out the different character codes e. g. by `Debug.Print Asc(Mid(Range.Value2, 1, 1))` and build a more/less difficult `Replace` function.

---

If you want to retain only a predefined set of characters, here's a simple function:

```
Private Function ReducedCharset(ByRef s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String
    Dim Temp As String
    Temp = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If c Like "[0-9A-Za-z€ÄÖÜßäöü]" Then
            Temp = Temp & c
        End If
    Next i
    ReducedCharset = Temp
End Function
```